# Focus textfields in order position with Keyboard. Swift 4.2, Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode

Let's assume there 4 textfields and 1 picker and 1 button in the current view controller. I have added two extra button on keyboard like below:

[image]

(Button images are not so important) What am i trying is: 
Let's assume I click on second textfield. And then app shows me keyboard with these buttons. I would like to switch textfields with these buttons. First button focus on previous(first textfield) Second button focus on next(third textfield). It should goes on like this in a loop.

Loop means: Let's assume user clicks 4th textfield. And then let's assume user next button on keyboard. So app should must focus on first textfield.

Here is the source code:

import UIKit
class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1Outlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2Outlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField3Outlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField4Outlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var contentViewOutlet: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textField1Outlet.delegate = self
    self.textField2Outlet.delegate = self
    self.textField3Outlet.delegate = self
    self.textField4Outlet.delegate = self

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let lastItemButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.rewind, target: self, action: #selector(self.switchToTheLastTextfield))
    let nextItemButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fastForward, target: self, action: #selector(self.switchToTheNextTextfield))

    toolBar.setItems([lastItemButton, nextItemButton], animated: false)

    textField1Outlet.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
    textField2Outlet.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
    textField3Outlet.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
    textField4Outlet.inputAccessoryView = UIView()

    textField1Outlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    textField2Outlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    textField3Outlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    textField4Outlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

@objc func switchToTheLastTextfield(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    **// help for this scope please**
}

@objc func switchToTheNextTextfield(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    **// help for this scope please**
}

}
```

I need to write these two methods: `switchToTheLastTextfield` and `switchToTheNextTextfield`. Maybe one method is enough to manage a focusing next and previos textfields.

I tried to implement these features with this method below, but it doesn't work fine. I tried this  method:

```
@objc func switchToTheNextTextfield()
{
    guard let contentView = self.contentViewOutlet else
    {
        return
    }
    for view in contentView.subviews
    {
        if let tField = view as? UITextField
        {
            if (tField == textField1Outlet)
            {
                textField2Outlet.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if (tField == textField2Outlet)
            {
                textField3Outlet.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if (tField == textField3Outlet)
            {
                textField4Outlet.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else if (tField == textField4Outlet)
            {
                textField1Outlet.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(`Swift 4.2, Xcode 10`)
By the way this is a detail: If next item is not a textfield App shouldn't crash. This scenerio should be managed also.

Comment: Use https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Dear @RajeshKumarR Actually, i don't want to use cocoa pod for this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

Declare a `UITextfield` variable and assign the current active textfield in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method.

Use your button action method to check the active textfield and use your logic of `becomeFirstResponder` in it.

```
var currentTextField = UITextField()

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.currentTextField = textField
}

@objc func switchToTheNextTextfield()
{
    switch self.currentTextField {
    case textField1Outlet:
        textField2Outlet.becomeFirstResponder()
    case textField2Outlet:
        textField3Outlet.becomeFirstResponder()
    case textField3Outlet:
        textField4Outlet.becomeFirstResponder()
    case textField4Outlet:
        textField1Outlet.becomeFirstResponder()
    default:
        print("Out of scope")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the main idea is to have an array that contains all of your textfields to make assigning first responders cleaner. Once that's set up, it's a matter of setting up your helper functions **switchToTheNextTextfield**, and **switchToTheLastTextfield**. In these functions, just iterate through the textfields and see which one is the current firstresponder, then make the next/previous textField in the array become first responder. Check out the sample code and comments.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1Outlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2Outlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField3Outlet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField4Outlet: UITextField!
// have a variable which is an array of the textFields to make it easy to cycle around without a long if condition
lazy var textFields: [UITextField] = [textField1Outlet, textField2Outlet, textField3Outlet, textField4Outlet]
@IBOutlet var contentViewOutlet: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // 1. These can be replaced with below
  /*
  self.textField1Outlet.delegate = self
  self.textField2Outlet.delegate = self
  self.textField3Outlet.delegate = self
  self.textField4Outlet.delegate = self
 */

  // 1. These can replace assigning each of the textFields delegate
  textFields.forEach { textField in
    textField.delegate = self
  }

  let toolBar = UIToolbar()
  toolBar.sizeToFit()

  let lastItemButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.rewind, target: self, action: #selector(self.switchToTheLastTextfield))
  let nextItemButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fastForward, target: self, action: #selector(self.switchToTheNextTextfield))

  toolBar.setItems([lastItemButton, nextItemButton], animated: false)

  // Don't need these since you'll immediate assign toolBar to the textFields
  /*
  textField1Outlet.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
  textField2Outlet.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
  textField3Outlet.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
  textField4Outlet.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
  */

  // These can also be replaced with the code below
  /*
  textField1Outlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
  textField2Outlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
  textField3Outlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
  textField4Outlet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
 */

  textFields.forEach { textField in
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
  }

}

@objc func switchToTheLastTextfield(_ textField: UITextField)
{
  guard let contentView = self.contentViewOutlet else
  {
    return
  }

  for (index, textField) in textFields.enumerated() {
    if textField.isFirstResponder {
      var previousIndex = index == 0 ? textFields.count - 1 : index - 1  // ternary to determine the previous index
      textFields[previousIndex].becomeFirstResponder()
      return
    }
  }
}

@objc func switchToTheNextTextfield()
{
  guard let contentView = self.contentViewOutlet else
  {
    return
  }

  for (index, textField) in textFields.enumerated() {
    if textField.isFirstResponder {
      var nextIndex = index == textFields.count - 1 ? 0 : index + 1   // ternary to determine the next index
      textFields[nextIndex].becomeFirstResponder()
      return
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general idea I would not cycle through your outlets “manually”: add all relevant (currently 4) inputs to a list and cycle through it with an extra variable that indicates the selected one.

Comment: can you help me about writing solution?

Comment: Please don't post "general ideas" as answers, rather use something that directly helps the OP

Comment: roger that! will try to!